# Is there an alternative to setting UIApplication idleTimerDisabled for iOS 6.1 to simply signify that the user has actively done something?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, external-accessory

I have an application which may, if it has the foreground, receive periodic updates from a hardware accessory. That hardware accessory has a physical hardware button on it.   The user perceives this as "interaction with the device" (iPhone or iPad touch in this case) and I would like these hardware button presses to reset the counter or timer mechanism inside the UIApplication so that it does not go immediately to sleep while the user is actively using the application.

How do I do that?  At the moment I can only disable the timer completely and then re-enable it from some internal secondary timer. All this timers-to-timers stuff seems silly.

I'm looking for a method like 
`[UIApplication userDidSomethingSoPleaseDontGoToSleepYouSillyThing];`

Right now if my application disables the idle timer and then forgets to re-enable it, the user's device will just run down the battery and turn off.  That's useful for battery lifetime testing, but would probably make an end user upset.  I'd rather not touch this idleTimerDisabled and simply tell the application to stay awake at least a while longer, and then if the user presses the button again, tell UIApplication to reset its internal timer again.

Comment: Answer: No there isn't. Just create an `NSTimer`, disable, and then re-enable when NSTimer fires (once or several times, you decide).

Answer (score 0):

maybe i don't understand you... but

```
/* Block idleTimer */
application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;

/* DO ALL YOUR STUFF */
/* AND IF SOMETHING APPEN */

/* Restore idleTimer */
application.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid because it is like a critical section. If you fail to exit this mode, you kill the battery. I was hoping that there was a system-api that says "keep the screen from dimming for 60 seconds and if you happen to not hear from me again, don't go killing the user's battery". But no there isn't. So you've pointed out what was already obvious. Thanks though. I am doing what you suggest (see my comment above) and that was the first obvious idea I tried, but I wanted something better.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand what you needed.

Comment: You could try to create an "idle timer disabling operation" called periodically in a different thread. 

If this operation meets all the requirements you can re-activate the idle timer, otherwise keep the idle timer disabled and wait for another call of this function.

Comment: Again that is what I have done. Only with an NSTimer instead of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following to reset the idle timer:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
});
```

Where 0.5 would be 0.5 seconds. Note that I didn't try this code myself. I'm not sure if there are (m)any conditions where the gcd block wouldn't execute.